# First allocation using dlmalloc

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am reading about Doug Lea's malloc implementation(dlmalloc) from http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html .

I understood that chunks contain size & other information along with memory space. The chunks are maintained in bins(in the form of linked list), according to size.

Whenever malloc is called with 'n' bytes, it looks for a chunk in suitable bin(which stores 'n' sized chunks) & if found, the chunk is removed from the bin.

And whenever free is called it inserts the block to be freed as a chunk in suitable bin.

So, my questions are -

1. At the beginning, when all the heap memory is unallocated/free, all bins should be empty, right?(since only free function inserts chunks in bins)
2. If this is the case, how(from where) first memory block will be allocated?
3. Can someone explain in detail about the 'designated victim'(dv) chunk & top chunk? What will be dv chunk at the time of first allocation?